# Is it possible to call the Windows API from Forth?

Tags: winapi, forth, gforth

In C/C++, Windows executables are linked against static libraries that import DLL files containing Windows API procedures.

But how do we access those procedures from Forth code (e.g. GForth)? Is it possible at all?

I'm aware that there's Win32Forth capable of doing Win32 stuff, but I'm interested how (and if) this could be done in Forth implementations that lack this functionality from the box (yet do run on target OS and are potentially able to interact with it on a certain level).

What currently comes up to my mind is loading the DLL files in question and somehow locating the address of a procedure to execute - but then, execute *how*? (All I know is that Windows API uses the [stdcall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) 
convention). And how do we locate a procedure without a C header? (I'm very new to Forth and just a bit less new to C++. Please bear with me if my musings are nonsense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do this in Gforth according to its documentation. The biggest problem will be dealing with call backs, which the Windows API relies on rather heavily. There is an unsupported package to deal with this, see *[5.25.6 Callbacks](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Callbacks.html)*. I have not attempted this myself in Gforth, but the documentation looks adequate.

You might also want to check [MPE's VFXForth](http://www.mpeforth.com/vfxcom.htm). From their website:

> Windows API Access
>
> VFX Forth can access all the standard Windows API calls, as well as functions in any other DLLs. The function interface allows API calls to be defined by cut and paste from other language reference manuals, for example:
>
> ```
> EXTERN: int PASCAL CreateDialogIndirectParam( HINSTANCE, void *,HWND, WNDPROC, LPARAM );
> EXTERN: int PASCAL SetWindowText( HANDLE, LPSTR );
> EXTERN: HANDLE PASCAL GetDlgItem( HANDLE, int );
> ```

This is down the page a bit at *[VFX Forth for Windows](http://www.mpeforth.com/vfxwin.htm)*.

As I do my Forth on Mac and Linux, I can't work through the Windows for Gforth to provide more detail, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

In general case, to implement foreign functions interface (FFI) for dynamically loaded libraries in some Forth system as extension (i.e., without changing source code and recompilation), we need the `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions, Forth assembler, and intimate knowledge of the Forth-system organization and ABI.
Sometimes it could be done even without assembler. For example, though [SP-Forth](http://spf.sourceforge.net/) has FFI, foreign calls were also [implemented](https://github.com/rufig/spf4-utf8/blob/master/devel/%7Epinka/spf/ffi/core.f) in pure Forth as a result of native code generation and union of the return stack with the native hardware stack.

Regarding Gforth, it seems that in the version 0.7.9 (see [releases](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/releases)) it doesn't have FFI for stdcall calling convention out of the box (it [supports cdecl](https://gforth.org/manual/C-Interface.html) only), although it has [dlopen and dlsym](https://gforth.org/manual/Low_002dLevel-C-Interface-Words.html), and [an assembler](https://gforth.org/manual/386-Assembler.html). So, it should be feasible to implement FFI for stdcall.

Answer (score 3):

Gforth 0.7.9 provides Windows API calls generated by Swig from the Windows header files.  The C interface uses a wrapper library, which is compiled by the C compiler, to pass parameters from the Forth stack to the system functions; as the C compiler understands stdcall, and the header files declare Windows API as stdcall, this "just works".

As all pre-generated C bindings live in the directory "unix" (for historical reasons), `include unix/win32.fs` gives you the win32 part of the Windows API.

Callbacks in the event loop are still a problem, as Gforth is a Cygwin program, and Cygwin has its special event loop task... but I hope that problem can be fixed.

Comment: It's a wonder and worth to know that Gforth for Windows is a Cygwin based application. I thought that the version for Windows it native.

Comment: @ruvim  GForth 0.7.0 doesn't require Cygwin to run on Windows 32- or 64-bit.  However, some of the innards (eg system and FFI/foreign function interface) use Cygwin dlls which are included.  See [this comment from Bernd Paysan creator] (https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.forth/c/8s9XVV1tmfA?pli=1)